# Post to multiple user profiles from a Facebook app

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, publish

I am developing a web application that I want to integrate with both Twitter and Facebook. At a certain time, messages will automatically be published on every user's feed, for both their Twitter and Facebook accounts.

I am currently working on the Facebook component. I know that in order to post to a user's feed on Facebook they must grant my app the publish_stream permission. Suppose I have a database of many users who have granted this permission. I want to publish a message on all of their feeds (visible to their friends). do I need to go through the database one-by-one and do an API call to post the message for each of them? This is the only way I can think of at the moment to do this, and it seems excessive to do this especially as the database gets larger and larger.

Is there a more efficient way to do what I describe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I say its the only way to do it - anyway - what you say looks like bulk messaging which might be thought as spam from facebook privacy policy point of view. If you want to use facebook's platform to do the spreading of the message, then create a facebook page and make your apps users to like that, otherwise you'll have to do it "by hand" - sending the message to each one of your users. This has a positive side effect - you can personalize the message for each of your user (mention their name, their friends name, etc), making your application more social.